80s French or German Romatic Drama - writer being interviewed
Date: Around the 80s.
Country of origin: Maybe French or German with Hungarian dubbing.
Genre: Romantic drama.
It begins with a writer being interviewed, he tells how he fell in love with a girl when he was a teenager, that story is the film.
It's set in the 50-60s, many people are seen getting around on bicycles. The boy is tall and blond, the girl is similar with slightly darker hair.
The relationship between them seemed rather formal and reserved by today's standards. There shared one kiss at the insistence of the girl during a walk they had. The boy was head over heels with the girl and wanted to marry her but the girl was taken aback how seriously the boy takes their relationship and this resulted in the girl losing interest and distancing herself. The don't get together, the end of the story is that the boy has never seen her again.
Some random bits:
The boy had a certain career plan before he met the girl, but after that, he wanted to work and not study, so that he can marry her. He asked a job from his father who tried to calm him and convince him that what he's doing isn't wise.
The boy had a little brother.
The boy and girl exchanged a lot of letters.
Once the girl snubbed the boy, by riding past him on a bicycle.
It could be a made for TV movie.
